# What is the Solution? x ≥8lgx

Tags: inequality, logarithms

x ≥ 8lgx

I have to find which x satisfy this inequality.
I found the points using graph, but I'd like someone to show me how to find it without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an analytical solution, you'll have to use the $W$ function.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: We have
$$x\geq8\log x$$ $$\frac{x}{8}\geq \log x$$ $$\log x\leq \frac{x}{8}$$ 
We know that $\log x$ is defined for all real values of $x$ such that $x\in(0, 1]$

Now, plot graphs of $y=\log x$ & straight line $y=\frac{x}{8}$

With the help of graphs, we find that both these graphs will intersect each other at a point say $x=a\ (>1)$ then the solution solution will be a set of real values $\color{red}{x\in(0, a]}$

Comment: I have already used Newton's Method to find the aprroximate values of x.

Comment: that's also good method for finding approximate real roots.

Comment: But there is not a single value there are infinitely many values satisfying the inequality.  Could you explain a bit of how you applied Newton's method?

Comment: Actually, if you plot the graphs of x and 8lgx they intersect at two points, which could be find by the Newton's Method by carefully choosing the guess value (or starting value). And then I simply adjust it to make sense as inequality so final results, to me, are x∈[0,1.57] and [6.51,∞). I suggest this could be proved,additionally by using Mean Value Theorem.